# Asp.net MVC DateTime.Now can not pass to model?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Thanks for reminder, so I added the content of model as well. I have a view with a form to post model to action, it is works now like below:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/ckeditor/ckeditor.js")">
</script>

<br />
<br />

@using (Html.BeginForm("BlogSubmit", "Blog", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "container"}))
{   
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
  <p class="text-warning">Blog Title</p>
    <div class="span6">
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.BlogTitles.Titles, new { @class = "input-xxlarge", @placeholder="Your blog title is here",@style="width: 500px"})
        </div>
<br />
 <br />
 <br />   
  <p class="text-warning">Blog Content</p>

   @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.BlogContents.Contents, new { @id = "editor1" });
    <br />
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit Blog</button>
}

<script>
    CKEDITOR.replace("editor1");    
</script>
```

Then below action get the model which is a `blogmodel` include all information for a blog.

**blogmodel**

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult BlogSubmit(BlogPageModel blogData)
{
    blogData.Blogs.LastModified = DateTime.Now;
    DB.BlogContenttbl.Add(new BlogContent { Contents = blogData.BlogContents.Contents });
    DB.BlogTitletbl.Add(new BlogTitle { Titles = blogData.BlogTitles.Titles });
    DB.SaveChanges();

    var blogTitleID = from t in DB.BlogTitletbl
                      where t.Titles == blogData.BlogTitles.Titles
                      select t.TitleID;
    var blogContentID = from c in DB.BlogContenttbl
                        where c.Contents == blogData.BlogContents.Contents
                        select c.ContentID;
    int blogTitleIDToInt = Convert.ToInt32(blogTitleID.First());
    int blogContentIDToInt = Convert.ToInt32(blogContentID.First());
    DB.Blogtbl.Add(new Blog { TitleID = blogTitleIDToInt, ContentID = blogContentIDToInt, LastModified = DateTime.Now });
    DB.SaveChanges();

    TempData["blog"] = blogData;
    return RedirectToAction("BlogPost");
}
```

**Model**

Here what I want clarify is this model view not the instance mapped to table, but only the model I created for view specially.

```
public class BlogPageModel
{
    public Blog Blogs { get; set; }
    public BlogAid BlogAids { get; set; }
    public BlogAuthor BlogAuthors { get; set; }
    public BlogComment BlogComments { get; set; }
    public BlogContent BlogContents { get; set; }
    public BlogNews BlogNews { get; set; }
    public BlogTitle BlogTitles { get; set; }
}
```

But, actually I want get blog *lastmodified* time and show in the *blogpost* view, the really model for blog which mapped to table is as below:

```
public class Blog
{
    public int BlogID { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastModified { get; set; }
    public System.Nullable<int> AidID { get; set; }
    public virtual BlogAid BlogAid{ get; set; }
    public System.Nullable<int> AuthorID { get; set; }
    public virtual BlogAuthor BlogAuthor { get; set; }
    public System.Nullable<int> CommentID { get; set; }
    public virtual BlogComment BlogComment { get; set; }
    public System.Nullable<int> TitleID { get; set; }
    public virtual BlogTitle BlogTitle { get; set; }
    public System.Nullable<int> ContentID { get; set; }
    public virtual BlogContent BlogContent { get; set; }
    public System.Nullable<int> NewsID { get; set; }
    public virtual BlogNews BlogNews { get; set; }
}
```

I really don't know why it doesn't work. And, I got below error with this line of code:

```
blogData.Blogs.LastModified = DateTime.Now;
```

**Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

Comment: Sounds like `blogData.Blogs` is `null`

Comment: Is your page model BlogPageModel?

Comment: Can you add your BlogPageModel class also?

Comment: blogData itself could be null.

Comment: Without the Model code, we really can't help you.

Comment: Set a break point here
blogData.Blogs.LastModified = DateTime.Now;

and check what is null, sounds like the blogs is null. There is nothing mapping to the blogs in your html code.

Answer (score -1):

try to instantiate the datetime, like

```
[...]
var now = new DateTime();
now = DateTime.Now;

DB.Blogtbl.Add(new Blog { TitleID = blogTitleIDToInt, ContentID = blogContentIDToInt,     LastModified = now   });

[...]
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.  `DateTime.Now` is a static property. As such, it does not require an instance of `DateTime`.

Comment: yes, i think so, the above method i used but really not what i wanted.

Answer (score -1):

```
new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Ticks)
```

Comment: Generally avoid code-only answers.  Consider adding a `description`.  Thanks